# How do I edit a dropdown that appears on the filter?

Tags: drupal, drop-down-menu

I have a big problem into modifying a thing on drupal..

I have a search filter for editing the content for the editors role, on which it appears a drop down for selecting node types..

However I can't find where to modify the list, because one wierd thing has happened
I have modified a node type's name and it dissapeared from the list...

I've tried like this by altering the url directly

http://gourmets.elperiodico.com/admin/editar-contenido?title=&type=NODE_NAME_MISSING

and it sais that I've entered an ilegal value..

Can someone help me solving this? I'm desperate because the editors can't edit a node type at all.

Comment: Can you export a copy of your view to [pastie.org](http://pastie.org) and link to it?